# Core dump in zmq library in a multi-threaded application with optimiized binary

Tags: gdb, zeromq, coredump

This core dump on zmq library happened on field (not reproducible yet) with an optimized binary.

```
#0 0x00007f44a00801f7 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1 0x00007f44a00818e8 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2 0x00007f44a1f74759 in zmq::zmq_abort(char const*) () from /lib64/libzmq.so.5
#3 0x00007f44a1fa410d in zmq::tcp_write(int, void const*, unsigned long) () from /lib64/libzmq.so.5
#4 0x00007f44a1f9f417 in zmq::stream_engine_t::out_event() () from /lib64/libzmq.so.5
#5 0x00007f44a1f7437a in zmq::epoll_t::loop() () from /lib64/libzmq.so.5
#6 0x00007f44a1fa83a6 in thread_routine () from /lib64/libzmq.so.5
#7 0x00007f44a1b2ce25 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#8 0x00007f44a014334d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6enter code here
```

While I am analyzing my application code and hoping to find some misuse of zmq (probably using same zmq socket by 2 different threads or some other memory corruption), I would like to know what else can i get from this core-dump?

For a start, I can see total 102 threads running at the dump time. A many of them are in the epoll_wait.

```
#0  0x00007f44a0143923 in epoll_wait () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007f44a1f74309 in zmq::epoll_t::loop() () from /lib64/libzmq.so.5
#2  0x00007f44a1fa83a6 in thread_routine () from /lib64/libzmq.so.5
#3  0x00007f44a1b2ce25 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#4  0x00007f44a014334d in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

The other threads pointing to application code do not look suspicious yet.

The errno printed is 14 = EFAULT (Bad address).

Can i try to get anything from the disassembly? I have not debugged many disassembly in the past. But in this situation if i can get any clue, i can jump-in.

Any (other) advice/pointer will also be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: In gdb, type `frame 2` in the thread you showed at the top of your question, then `print *(char *)$rdi` . This should show the error message that zmq_abort printed out before it aborted the process.

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing the code.

Comment: I missed mentioning, i got the errno as 14 = EFAULT (Bad address)

Comment: @Mark Plotnick, 
(gdb) f 2
#2  0x00007f44a1f74759 in zmq::zmq_abort(char const*) () from /lib64/libzmq.so.5
(gdb) print *(char *)$rdi
Cannot access memory at address 0x7c2
(gdb)